# Mongoose not saving child document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, insert

I am trying to insert into my collection, and it does insert, but the sub document is not getting saved, and I am not sure why.

I have this **scheme/model**:

```
import { Schema, Document, Model, model } from 'mongoose'

export interface IPerson {
  name: {
    first: string
    last: string
  }
  dob: Date
}

export interface IPersonModel extends IPerson, Document { }

let nameSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  first: String,
  last: String
})
let PersonName = model('PersonName', nameSchema)

export var personSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: { child: PersonName.schema },
  dob: Date
}, { timestamps: true })

export const Person: Model<IPersonModel> = model<IPersonModel>('Person', personSchema, 'people')
```

I am using express to pass in the data and use the **model** like so:

```
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser'
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/save/:type', async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.xhr) res.sendStatus(400)
  let p = new Person({
    name: {
      first: req.body.first,
      last: req.body.last
    },
    dob: new Date()
  })
  p.save((err, data) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log('Saved : ', data);
  })
  res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

When I save, I get the following output to the terminal:

```
Saved :  { __v: 0,
    updatedAt: 2017-07-02T14:52:18.286Z,
    createdAt: 2017-07-02T14:52:18.286Z,
    dob: 2017-07-02T14:52:18.272Z,
    _id: 595908a27de708401b107e4b 
}
```

So, Why is my child `name` not getting saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what I needed to do was change `child` to `type` like so:

```
name: { child: PersonName.schema }
```

to

```
name: { type: PersonName.schema }
```

By passing a schema, this also creates an `_id`, so I was able to change that by instead of passing a schema, just pass an object like so:

```
name { type: { first: String, last: String } }
```